# Border around meter element in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox, meter

Trying to style the HTML5 `meter` element, I noticed that Chrome renders the border in a different way than Firefox. Actually, it ignores the color entirely.

```css
meter {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  
  background: #ccc;
  
  border: 5px solid #f00;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
  background: #ccc;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  background: #0a0;
}

meter::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: #0a0;
}
```

```html
<meter value="50" min="0" max="100">
```

Adding the border to `-webkit-meter-bar` works as intended in Chrome, but if I add a border to both `meter` (for Firefox) and `-webkit-meter-bar` (for Chrome), the element will have a double-border in Chrome.

Why does Chrome ignore the border color and is there a way to style the `meter` in such a way that it looks the same in Chrome and Firefox except using a wrapper with its own border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option you got here is to give different styles to the border of the meter in firefox and chrome (border in firefox, no border in chrome), and use the `-webkit-meter-bar` to set the border in chrome.

You can use the `@-moz-document url-prefix()` hack in order to do this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    meter {
        border: 5px solid #f00;
    }
}
```

Here is an example:

```css
meter {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    meter {
        border: 5px solid #f00;
    }
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 5px solid #f00;
}

meter::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: #0a0;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  background: #0a0;
}
```

```html
<meter value="50" min="0" max="100"></meter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `meter` is a relatively new element, it will take time for similar results across browsers.

However, you can try setting `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px #000;`
The fourth property sets the shadow expansion (border size in this case). The fifth property is the color.

The disadvantage is that you don't get border styles, only a solid border

**SNIPPET:**

```css
meter {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  padding:0;
  border: 5px solid #f00;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
  background: #ccc;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  background: #0a0;
}

meter::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: #0a0;
}

meter{
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 5px #f00;
  }
```

```html
<meter value="50" min="0" max="100">
```